# In fortran, why interface has a name? what does it do when you call the interface?

Tags: interface, fortran, call, subroutine

The subroutine `inoutput_finalize` calls the interface finalise.  It is really weird, the interface finalize contains the subroutine `inoutput_finalize` ? Does subroutine `inoutput_finalize` call itself in the subroutine?

````
  public :: finalise
  interface finalise
     module procedure inoutput_finalise
  end interface finalise


subroutine inoutput_finalise(this)
    type(Inoutput), intent(inout)::this
    if (this%unit .ge. 7)  close(this%unit)
    call finalise(this%verbosity_stack)
    call finalise(this%verbosity_cascade_stack)
    call deactivate(this)
    this%initialised = .false.
  end subroutine inoutput_finalise```
````

Comment: The answer to the linked question gives a lot of detail about what interface blocks mean.  The crucial part here is that `finalise` is a generic interface with specific procedure `inoutput_finalise`.

Comment: No, it does NOT call itself, it is calling a **generic** function which has many specific functions. It is calling a *different* specific functions. Please make sure to read the link you were given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068442/fortran-difference-between-generic-and-specific-interfaces and read it thoroughly.

Comment: Note that there are another `interface finalise` in other parts of your code and they define the other specific functions. Look for other interfaces with the same name in your codebase.

Comment: I just found another 'interface Finalise' with capital F.  In the subroutine 'inoutput_finalise', it calls finalise not Finalise.  Does the compiler know it should call interface Finalise?

Comment: In Fortran case of the characters makes no difference outside of character contexts

Comment: Please do not completely rewrite your questions in this way. I rolled your edit back, We cannot see what exactly it calls without a complete code anyway. As Ian told you, there is no difference between `finalise` and `Finalise`, they are completely identaical. Even if it were `FiNaLiSe` it would have been identical. If you wish to rewrite your question to something that can be reopened, you must make the question complete and consistent. Please read [ask] and [mcve] very carefully.

Comment: But most likely the answer is yes, it calls `Stack_Finalise`. You could easily verify it yourself by adding some `print` statements or stepping through your program in a debugger. It is very likely but to be sure we would need to see *much more code*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and kind advices.  This is my first time to use stack overflow.  I will learn how to use this platform properly.  I am glad to join this fantastic community.