# What does module procedure do inside interface blocks in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, procedure, subroutine, fortran95

My supervisor at university has tasked me with reverse-engineering some Fortran 95 code. I have struggled to find good documentation on it. There's a module that contains this:

```
interface get_HS_blocks 
  module procedure TBModel_get_HS_blocks
end interface get_HS_blocks
```

I was watching some videos on youtube and the guy in the videos was saying that you «interface blocks to instruct the compiler on how to behave when the datatype that is passed into a procedure can change». In this case, I guess that means that

1. `get_HS_blocks` calls `TBModel_get_HS_blocks`?

But later, `TBModel_get_HS_blocks` calls `get_HS_blocks` itself:

```
subroutine TBModel_get_HS_blocks(this, at, i, j, dv_hat, dv_mag, b_H, b_S, i_mag)
  type(TBModel), intent(in) :: this
  type(Atoms), intent(in) :: at
  integer, intent(in) :: i, j
  real(dp), intent(in) :: dv_hat(3), dv_mag
  real(dp), intent(out) :: b_H(:,:), b_S(:,:)
  integer, intent(in), optional :: i_mag

  select case(this%functional_form)
    case (FF_NRL_TB)
      call get_HS_blocks(this%tbmodel_nrl_tb, at, i, j, dv_hat, dv_mag, b_H, b_S, i_mag)
    case (FF_Bowler)
      call get_HS_blocks(this%tbmodel_bowler, at, i, j, dv_hat, dv_mag, b_H, b_S, i_mag)
    case (FF_DFTB)
      call get_HS_blocks(this%tbmodel_dftb, at, i, j, dv_hat, dv_mag, b_H, b_S, i_mag)
    case (FF_GSP)
      call get_HS_blocks(this%tbmodel_gsp, at, i, j, dv_hat, dv_mag, b_H, b_S)
    case default
      call system_abort ('TBModel_get_HS_blocks confused by functional_form' // this%functional_form)
  end select

end subroutine
```

So if (1) above was correct, `get_HS_blocks` would be recursively called indefinitely ?!

Can you briefly explain what module procedure does inside the interface block, and what happens when `get_HS_blocks` calls `TBModel_get_HS_block` ?

Comment: If you haven't looked yet, see if your university library has a copy of Metcalf et al, Modern Fortran Explained.  It will tell you what a module procedure is.  The initial code is defining a generic interface with the name `get_HS_blocks`.  When the compiler see `get_HS_blocks`, it will look for, in this case, a subroutine that appears in the interface with a matching interface (i.e., type, kind, and rank of the arguments must match).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Modules and scroll down to `interface block`.

Comment: And some of these interface blocks can be used very pointlessly. I know a scientific code where they put every public procedure into a generic interface, usually with a single specific procedure. It causes very non-specific error messages when the procedure is called incorrectly.

Comment: In addition to the question linked as a duplicate see also the comments at [In fortran, why interface has a name? what does it do when you call the interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67730589/in-fortran-why-interface-has-a-name-what-does-it-do-when-you-call-the-interfac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава so this is roughtly what I expect. Does get_HS_blocks call TBModel_get_HS_block and again calls get_HS_blocks in an infinite recursive loop?