# How to avoid rewriting the same interface for a deferred type-bound procedure implemented in a submodule?

Tags: fortran

Consider the following code, which defines an `abstract` type `foo` with a `deferred` procedure `sub`, and a type `foo2` which extends `foo`:

```
MODULE m
  TYPE, ABSTRACT:: foo
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE(sub_int), DEFERRED:: sub
  END TYPE

  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE sub_int(THIS, x)
      IMPORT:: foo
      CLASS(foo), INTENT(IN):: THIS
      DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT):: x
    END SUBROUTINE
  END INTERFACE

  TYPE, EXTENDS(foo):: foo2
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE:: sub
  END TYPE

  INTERFACE
    MODULE SUBROUTINE sub(THIS, x)
      CLASS(foo2), INTENT(IN):: THIS
      DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT):: x
    END SUBROUTINE
  END INTERFACE
END MODULE

SUBMODULE (m) s
CONTAINS
  MODULE PROCEDURE sub
    x= x**2
  END PROCEDURE
END SUBMODULE
```

Is there a way to avoid writing the second `interface`?

I understand that it is needed in order to declare `sub` as a `module procedure` (otherwise the implementation would need to be done in the `module`, and not in the `submodule`), but is this the only way to do it?

In other words, is it possible to implement the procedure `sub` for `foo2` without rewriting the entire interface for it?

Comment: It is not just rewritten. Once you have `class(foo)`, and later `class(foo2)`. Once the interface block is abstract and later it isn't.

Comment: The interface block in MODULE a is not `ABSTRACT` in my example. Also, I am not sure if  `CLASS(foo2)` really adds anything to `CLASS(foo)`...any type that extends `foo` will be of `CLASS(foo)`, so the overriding procedures in the extended types WILL require a type `foo` argument. Please correct me if I am wrong. In any case, do you know if this is the only way to achieve what I describe in my example?

Comment: Sorry, your `sub_int` interface block indeed isn't abstract but it perhaps should actually be. But there is is still the difference between just `subroutine` and `module subroutine`. You are not just copying the same stuff.

Comment: I actually did not use an abstract interface on purpose, to show that in my opinion, at least some of the information (the arguments of the procedure) are repeated, and the code allows for it. I use abstract interfaces in my actual code, for deferred type-bound procedures, and I agree that they should be used for this purpose. However, I just would like to know if this the only way to do it, or if there are other ways that can make me "spare" some lines of code.

Comment: I don't believe it is currently possible to do what you want. There are [proposals](https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals/issues/120) to add such things to a future Fortran standard.

Comment: @VladimirF Regarding abstract and specific interfaces, in your comment above you said the interface `sub_int` in my example SHOULD perhaps be abstract. However, in a comment to your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068442/difference-between-fortrans-abstract-and-normal-interfaces you said "You never strictly need abstract interfaces". I think using an abstract interface is preferable for a deferred type-bound procedure, because it does not "exist" yet. However, since the code compiles also with a specific interface, what is your motivation for preferring an abstract interface?

Comment: I said that meanin "you can always write an actual procedure of that name and just use `procedure(name_of_the_actual_procedure)`. But if the interface blocks refers to something that is not a procedure existing under that name, it should be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  A separate module subprogram requires an interface block, either in its defining submodule or an ancestor of its defining submodule.

Whether a procedure happens to be nominated by one (or more!) bindings of one (or more!) types is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the comment to the question by @veryreverie, there is a link to a discussion about this issue, and a solution using preprocessor macros is suggested. A macro is used to avoid the rewriting of the entire interface; the macro is written instead. It seems very useful to me, but is it recommended to use preprocessor macros for this purpose, or is it considered (more or less) bad practice? If it is bad practice, why is it so?

Comment: That strikes me as being an unrelated question.  I don't use macros.  I consider them bad practice in "Fortran" code.  For one - as soon as you use them, your code is no longer Fortran, as defined by ISO/IEC 1539-1.