# OOP Fortran : how to put "abstract derived type", "abstract interface" and submodules ALL TOGETHER?

Tags: oop, module, fortran, abstract-class

This question follow this one([fortran, how to have a number of variable dimensions in dimension (allocatable) , allocate and affectation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72415025/7462275)).

Frederico suggested me to use OOP and gave me a solution to my initial problem.
Now, I would like to use submodule (cf 4. The advantages of submodules in https://fortran.bcs.org/2004/ukfortran04.htm).

This is my code :

```
module grids
   implicit none

   type, abstract, public :: grid
      contains
      procedure (grid_init), deferred :: init
   end type grid
   
   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid2D
      real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: myArray
      contains
         procedure :: init=>grid_init
   end type grid2D
   
   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid3D
      real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: myArray
      contains
         procedure :: init=>grid_init
   end type grid3D

   ! Define procedure APIs 
   abstract interface
      module subroutine grid_init(this,size)
         class(grid), intent(inout) :: this
         integer, intent(in) :: size
      end subroutine grid_init
   end interface
   
end module grids

submodule (grids) grid2D
   contains
   
   module procedure grid_init
      allocate(this%myArray(size,size))
   end subroutine grid_init
   
end submodule grid2D
   

submodule (grids) grid3D    
   contains
   
   module procedure grid_init
      allocate(this%myArray(size,size,size))
   end subroutine grid_init
   
end submodule grid3D

program main

    use grids
    
    type(grid2D) :: myGrid
    
    call myGrid%init(3)
    print *,myGrid%myArray
    
end program main
```

But, it does not compile because `grid_init` is an `abstract interface`. What must I change in this code ?

## edit 1

Federico said in his answer : *To put in a submodule only the routines, without the type definition, you may have to define additional interfaces for all their functions, which is nonsense.* I understand clearly the problem. This part of code illustrates well the problem (For sake of brevity, module `grids_base` is omitted but it is unchanged and the same modifications applied to grids_3d)

```
module grids_2d 
   use grids_base
   implicit none
   
   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid2D
      real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: myArray
      contains
         procedure :: init=>grid_init2d
   end type grid2D   
      
   interface
        module subroutine grid_init2d(this,size)
            class(grid2D), intent(out) :: this
            integer, intent(in) :: size
        end subroutine grid_init2d
   end interface
   
end module grids_2d

submodule (grids_2d) grid_2dsub
   contains
   
   module procedure grid_init2d
      allocate(this%myArray(size,size))
   end procedure grid_init2d
   
end submodule grid_2dsub
```

I wonder, if it is possible (with some "OOP tricks", that I am not aware of) to simplify this code because `grid_init2d` interface is very similar to the `grid_init` abstract interface. The only difference is the `class` of `this` : `grid` changes to`grid2D` but the type `grid2D` is derived from `grid` where the abstract interface `grid_init` is defined.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of bother and forget about OOP - a 30yr diversion down the wrong road for software construction.  But if you insist, have a look at 
https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming, in particular at the series of articles originally published by the Portland Group which are referenced there.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. *Save myself a lot of of bother", I agree. But, why should I forget about OOP a 30yr diversion ...? Because of a loss in performance ?

Comment: My objections to OOP derive from the folly of too-tightly coupling data structures and routines, not from performance issues.  But it's a big topic and not one I'm inclined to go further into in a series of comments on a question about how to use Fortran's facilities for OOP.  A study of some of the references on the Fortran Wiki page should help you towards an answer to your immediate question.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is complaining not because of the submodule, but cause you're pointing to an `abstract` routine. the `interface` keyword means you're only defining an API, not an actual implementation. To put in a submodule only the routines, without the type definition, you may have to define additional `interface`s for all their functions, which is nonsense, but AFAICT the Fortran standard doesn't consider this yet.

I think the most elegant/standard way to do this is to have each class with its own module, and only use submodules in case the class-specific file gets too large. In your case, you'd have:

```
module grids_base
   implicit none

   type, abstract, public :: grid
      contains
      procedure (grid_init), deferred :: init
   end type grid

   ! Define procedure APIs 
   abstract interface
      module subroutine grid_init(this,size)
         class(grid), intent(out) :: this
         integer, intent(in) :: size
      end subroutine grid_init
   end interface
   
end module grids_base

module grids_2d 
   use grids_base
   implicit none
   
   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid2D
      real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: myArray
      contains
         procedure :: init=>grid_init2d
   end type grid2D   
   
   contains
   
   subroutine grid_init2d(this,size)
      class(grid2D), intent(out) :: this
      integer, intent(in) :: size
      allocate(this%myArray(size,size))
   end subroutine grid_init2d
   
end module grids_2d
   

module grids_3d 
   use grids_base    
   implicit none   
   
   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid3D
      real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: myArray
      contains
         procedure :: init=>grid_init3d
   end type grid3D   
   
   contains
   
   subroutine grid_init3d(this,size)
      class(grid3D), intent(out) :: this
      integer, intent(in) :: size
      allocate(this%myArray(size,size,size))
   end subroutine grid_init3d
   
end module grids_3d

! Global interface to grids
module grids
  use grids_base
  use grids_2d
  use grids_3d
  implicit none
end module grids  


program main

    use grids
    
    type(grid2D) :: myGrid
    
    call myGrid%init(3)
    print *,myGrid%myArray
    
end program main
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I post a code in a answer. It is not really an answer. It is to discuss and the code is too long for a comment.

Comment: I wrote an edit to my question.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was referring to. I'm not aware of other ways to do that though.

Comment: Answer herre : https://stackoverflow.com/q/69333511/7462275 and here https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals/issues/120